# My answer on my own question gets downvoted

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I asked a question on www.stackoverflow.com and got a downvote and some answers. The answers didn't help me, but eventually I found the solution and decided to answer my question so other people know how I fixed the problem. This answer also got a downvote without a reason, because I just said what I did wrong. It was an easy solution but nobody else said it.

Why did I get downvoted?

Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367223/ajax-on-click-not-working

Thanks

Comment: You should ask questions about a specific site (and a specific question in this case) on that site's meta ([Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) in this case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the answer is something only you could find, that's the problem when a question has no [minimum complete and verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Your question as it is can NOT be of help for someone else, and same for your answer.

The tooltip on the vote button says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful

I assume downvoters classified your question and answer as not useful, and maybe without any research effort shown.

When asking things like this, try to explain what you already did to solve the problem and to ask do your best to reproduce the problem with the minimum code to include in the question, during this process you're likley to answer yourself, but if not you'll give enough material for others to help you.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, however anybody could've found the answer since in the code it said `$_SESSION[]` but not `session_start()`.

Comment: Your code looks like an excerpt of your whole file code, not a whole file...

Comment: @martin what I mean is : how someone is supposed to guess you php code block is the whole file? There is no open / close tag an se tou don't say a word about it. And even as such, that's a kind of typo with no real value on long term as someone having the same kind of problem will have a hard time finding the answer in your Q/A pair from google as the problem is too localized when you don't notice you forget start_session

Comment: Should I have not answered? Then people maybe would have continued looking for an answer.

Comment: @Martin you may have deleted the question, comments have directed you to a bunch of flaws in your code, which SO community doesn't wish to keep visible to not encourage bad practices.